# ::before directly not worked in css

Tags: css, html

i tried to using ::before element in HTML directly.
my code is below

```
<ul class="clear toogled" style="height:188pxl">
<li tabindex="0" style="display: block;">
<label for="MAP-IA_1_1_OR_CB_1" aria-label="Filter by product">
::before
hello
</label>
</ul>
```

this will gives output like this

```
::before
hello
```

why it gives output like this?

Comment: Because that's not how it works.

Comment: what other output are you expecting? (as a side note height:188`pxl` is not correct)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: Should apply a css rule to your label or put `hello` between a `span` tag and add a `::before` pseudo element on it.

Comment: :before and :after are CSS pseudo elements. There are several good guides out there explaining them, you should read into a few before asking here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/.

Comment: i actually wrtite a code that is look like [link]http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/ when we click on class on that site it displyed sub options in thier websites they used ::before and ::after similary to that site i too used for my HTML page but my code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are aiming for exactly, but as the others have mentioned, that is not how you use the "before" pseudo element.

Basically, those ::before and ::after elements you see on the DOM are *automatically* inserted into the DOM by CSS pseudo classes `:before` and `:after`.

For example, using your code I can put a coffee mug in front of your 'hello'.

```css
label:before{
  content:"\2615";
}
```

```html
<ul class="clear toogled" style="height:188pxl">
  <li tabindex="0" style="display: block;">
  <label for="MAP-IA_1_1_OR_CB_1" aria-label="Filter by product">
  hello
  </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

All I did was create a CSS selector `label:before` and set it's content to a unicode character, which basically says, before anything inside the of the label, I want to show `content`.

If you inspect the Samsung site from which you copied the HTML from, you can verify that they do the same thing.

Here is the [resource](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) I used when I initially started learning about the `:before` pseudo class.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation.now i am bit better than past :) and also i am new to this site.

Comment: Your welcome! It was certainly not straight forward for me when I learned this too. If you feel my explanation helped, feel free to upvote the answer or accept the answer.